# Mongo Db aggregation $redact error on shell

Tags: mongodb

I make an aggregate in mongo db.  I have this error

> $redact's expression should not return anything aside from the variables &&KEEP, $$DESCEND and $$PRUNE, but returned {if:true}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) does not have a [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) statment within it's arguments:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": <logical condition>
            "then": < something like $$KEEP or $$PRUNE or $$DESCEND >,
            "else": < something like $$KEEP or $$PRUNE (etc) depending on which is false >
        }
    }}
])
```

It's all covered in the manual page as linked.